# How do I assign same rank to users with the same score with PHP?

Tags: php, sql

```
$check_res = $con->query(
        "SELECT * 
        FROM `results` 
        WHERE school_session='$session' 
        AND Term='$term' 
        AND class='$class' 
        AND  subjectID='$subjectID' 
        ORDER BY Average DESC ");

$score_ends = array(1 => "st", 2 => "nd", 3 => "rd", 4 => "th");
$key_counter=1;
foreach ($check_res as $value) {
    $key_counters=$key_counter++;
    if($RegNum == $value['StudentReg']){
        if($key_counters < 4){
            echo $key_counters.$score_ends[$key_counters];
        }else{
            echo $key_counters.$score_ends[4];
        }
    }
}
```

this code up here ranks users based on average. Its works fine on that.
But it does not assign same rank to users with same average score.
E.g
20-1st
20-2nd

but what i want is this
20-1st
20-1st
21-3rd

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will work on that now

Comment: What is `$RegNum` and where is it being defined?

Comment: $RegNum is the unique identity of each user

Comment: What should happen if more than 3 people get the top score?

Comment: neville kuyt same outcome

Comment: Which 3 people do you want to show, if there are 4 who have the top score?

Comment: Nevile Kuyt. If they all have the same score, they should all be ranked on the same position no matter the number of people with the same score. Do you get the point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Talking points

So there are a few things with your code that aren't *best practice* or are a bit confusing.

- You should really use `prepared` statements with you SQL queries. They offer far better protection when using user derived data (it isn't clear whether your search parameters are from user input or from other code)
- If you're using `$variables` in your double quoted strings it's good practice to use `{curly braces}` to encompass them. It solves a variety of issues with `PHP` using the correct variable and also makes it easier to read and maintain
- As others have said you haven't actually shown where `$Reg` has come from  - so I have ignored it in the following code

### Solution

#### Table/Data

Assuming that you have the following data in your table...

**Table: results**

```
StudentReg | school_session | Term | class | subjectID | Average
-----------+---------------+------+-------+-----------+-------------
1          | 1022           | 3    | 37    | 66        | 121
2          | 1022           | 3    | 37    | 66        | 115
3          | 1022           | 3    | 37    | 66        | 129
4          | 1022           | 3    | 37    | 66        | 121
5          | 1022           | 3    | 37    | 66        | 121
6          | 1022           | 3    | 37    | 66        | 117
7          | 1022           | 3    | 37    | 66        | 129
8          | 1022           | 3    | 37    | 66        | 125
9          | 1022           | 3    | 37    | 66        | 120
10         | 1022           | 3    | 37    | 66        | 118
11         | 1022           | 3    | 37    | 66        | 125
12         | 1022           | 3    | 37    | 66        | 124
13         | 1022           | 3    | 37    | 66        | 125
14         | 1022           | 3    | 37    | 66        | 125
```

**Sorted data returned by query**

```
StudentReg | school_session | Term | class | subjectID | Average
-----------+---------------+------+-------+-----------+-------------
2          | 1022           | 3    | 37    | 66        | 115
6          | 1022           | 3    | 37    | 66        | 117
10         | 1022           | 3    | 37    | 66        | 118
9          | 1022           | 3    | 37    | 66        | 120
1          | 1022           | 3    | 37    | 66        | 121
5          | 1022           | 3    | 37    | 66        | 121
4          | 1022           | 3    | 37    | 66        | 121
8          | 1022           | 3    | 37    | 66        | 125
12         | 1022           | 3    | 37    | 66        | 124
11         | 1022           | 3    | 37    | 66        | 125
13         | 1022           | 3    | 37    | 66        | 125
14         | 1022           | 3    | 37    | 66        | 125
3          | 1022           | 3    | 37    | 66        | 129
7          | 1022           | 3    | 37    | 66        | 129
```

#### Code

I have adapted the code to use `prepared` statements.

**variables**

Presumably these are declared somewhere further up your code...

```
$session   = 1022;
$term      = 3;
$class     = 37;
$subjectID = 66;
```

**mysqli**

```
// SQL query to SELECT "Average" and "StudentReg" from "results"
// ?s are a place holder for values we'll bind later
$sql   = "
    SELECT StudentReg, Average
    FROM `results` 
    WHERE school_session = ? 
        AND Term = ? 
        AND class = ? 
        AND subjectID = ?
    ORDER BY Average DESC
";

$query  = $mysqli->prepare();                                    // Prepare the query
$query->bind_param("iiii", $session, $term, $class, $subjectID); // Bind search values to parameters ("iiii" : one "i" for each variable, set's data type to "int")
$query->execute();                            // Run the query
$query->Store_result();                       // Store the result set
$query->bind_result($studentreg, $average);   // Bind returned rows to variables

$score_ends = array(1 => "st", 2 => "nd", 3 => "rd", 4 => "th");
$last_value = false;     // Initialise last value of result set
### $counter    = 0;     // Initialise the counter
$rank = 0;
while($query->fetch()){  // Loop through the result set
    ### $counter++;      // Increment the counter

    ### // "if" statement using ternary logic
    ### // Sets the rank as either the counter OR the previous rank if it's the same
    ### $rank = ($last_value == false || $last_value <> $average) ? $counter : $rank;

    // "if" statement using ternary logic
    // Pre-increments (++ before variable) rank if the Average is not the same as previous
    // ...or leaves as is if it is the same
    $rank = ($last_value == false || $last_value <> $average) ? ++$rank: $rank;
    $end = ($rank > 3) ? $score_ends[4] : $score_ends[$rank];  // Sets the suffix to the rank using ternary logic
    echo "{$rank}{$end} {$studentreg}<br>";                     // Prints the result; e.g. 1st 2 {2 == the StudentReg, presumably you'll update that to be a name or something}
    $last_value = $average;                                    // Sets current average as last value ready for next loop
}
```

**PDO**

```
// SQL query to SELECT "Average" and "StudentReg" from "results"
// ?s are a place holder for values we'll bind later
$sql   = "
    SELECT StudentReg, Average
    FROM `results` 
    WHERE school_session = ? 
        AND Term = ? 
        AND class = ? 
        AND subjectID = ?
    ORDER BY Average DESC
";

$query  = $PDO->prepare();                               // Prepare the query
$query->execute([$session, $term, $class, $subjectID]);  // Execute the query and bind variables to place holders
$score_ends = array(1 => "st", 2 => "nd", 3 => "rd", 4 => "th");
$last_value = false;     // Initialise last value of result set
### $counter    = 0;     // Initialise the counter
$rank = 0;
while($query->fetch()){  // Loop through the result set
    ### $counter++;      // Increment the counter

    ### // "if" statement using ternary logic
    ### // Sets the rank as either the counter OR the previous rank if it's the same
    ### $rank = ($last_value == false || $last_value <> $row["Average"]) ? $counter : $rank;

    // "if" statement using ternary logic
    // Pre-increments (++ before variable) rank if the Average is not the same as previous
    // ...or leaves as is if it is the same
    $rank = ($last_value == false || $last_value <> $row["Average"]) ? ++$rank: $rank;

    $end = ($rank > 3) ? $score_ends[4] : $score_ends[$rank] ; // Sets the suffix to the rank using ternary logic
    echo "{$rank}{$end} {$row["StudentReg"]}<br>";             // Prints the result; e.g. 1st 2 {2 == the StudentReg, presumably you'll update that to be a name or something}
    $last_value = $row["Average"];                             // Sets current average as last value ready for next loop
}
```

**Output**

```
1st     2
2nd     6
3rd     10
4th     9
5th     1
5th     5
5th     4
8th     8
9th     12
10th    11
10th    13
10th    14
13th    3
13th    7
```

Comment: wow...so clean!! Thanks brother. I will work on your advice also. Thanks so much

Comment: Yes Steven. I love the arrangement of the script.  but i still got some questions to ask

Comment: @Green Okay, what questions?

Comment: Your script is very clean, it gave me what I want in a better way. But I still need your help. The output is this: 1st-21, 1st-21, 3rd-22. But I want something like this: 1st-21, 1st-21, 2nd-22 instead of jumping straight to 3rd, I want it to continue the sequence. Pls. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Green what's the next problem then? If it's _unrelated_ to this, original, question it's best to "ask a new question" and we'll go from there

Comment: Your script is very clean, it gave me what I want in a better way. But I still need your help. The output is this: 1st-21, 1st-21, 3rd-22. But I want something like this: 1st-21, 1st-21, 2nd-22 instead of jumping straight to 3rd, I want it to continue the sequence. Pls. Thanks in advance.....This is the question i asked sir

Comment: @Green Okay, I've updated the code commenting out the lines that pertain to skipping rank with `###` so you know what they are. Note that I've also updated the `ternary` statement to give what you need.

Comment: But one more thing. The output from the database is bring out more than queried. For example, what is demanded is average scores from only sss 1 students but its also bringing out some averages from sss 2. Ive checked your query but i see no issue with it. Pls help

Comment: @Green what do you mean by `sss 1`?

Comment: thats one of the classes in the portal

Comment: thats one of the classes in the school

Comment: @Green hmm that's odd... Can you update the query to select `class, Term, subjectID` as well? Then dump all that data (assuming you're using PDO `$query->fetchAll()` and double check that your data is returning incorrect results?

Comment: its now showing an error saying the rank variable is undefined. Im using the mysqli not the PDO

Comment: @Green That's my bad! It's because we didn't set the variable `$rank` before using it in code. It should be a `notice` as opposed to a warning? I'll update the code! (All you need to do is initialise it outside of the loop like `$rank = 0;`

Comment: Working Now! Thanks Bro. The only isssue now is the query i spoke of earlier. I think the only query being processed is the subjectID. Its like the others are non-existent. its not seeing the class, session and Term. I tried to tweak these but no changes. Changes only comes when i tweak the subjectID

Comment: @Green were you able to get a dump of the returned results?

Comment: Yes i did using Var_dump

Comment: C:\wamp64\www\Check\Admin\checkbox\string.php:181:null

Comment: @Green that's not right - where did you try and take the `var_dump` from?  It should be between the `$query->execute();`  and `$score_ends = array(..);` lines? Just like: `var_dump($query->fetchAll());`

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I just tried it, its returning an error

Comment: This: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetchAll() in C:\wamp64\www\command\Administration\checkbox\string.php on line 160
( ! ) Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetchAll() in C:\wamp64\www\command\Administration\checkbox\string.php on line 160

Comment: @Green that's because `fetchAll` isn't a `mysqli` method it's `PDO`!

Comment: @Green underneath your `bind_result` put something like: `echo "<pre>"; while($query->fetch()){echo "SR: {$studentreg}, AVG: {$average}\n";}exit;`

Comment: it brought the exact number selected by the query this time

Comment: @Green then what happens to make you think that it doesn't filter otherwise??

Comment: @steven...thanks so much. everything is in place now. I didnt notice it. Thanks so much for your patience

Comment: @Steven...i have another question but not pertaining to this. Its differnt from this

Comment: @Green, no problem. If this answered your question you can [mark it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419). If you have another question which is different then you can ask [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do the ranking directly in the database, using window functions:

```
select r.*, rank() over(order by average desc) rn 
from results r
where 
    school_session = ?
    and term = ?
    and class = ?
    and  subjectid = ?
order by average desc
```

`rank()` assigns the same number to ties.

Note that I changed the query to use parameters rather than concatenating php variables in the query string: this is both safer and more efficient.

Comment: GMB Yes but not using 8.0 at the moment. I will upgrade soon. But please any other way for now